# Node js request entity too large with multer upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

well I've tried different ways to upload a 200k file increased the limit changed parameters, did everything I changed the multer. Fucei everything I knew what I read in the stack, which I found on google the basic google search is done my problem and not up but down the pictures works like a charm. the server supports upload images I atualemente do this task with php but if not roll in nodejs, I'll do the same files in php. thanks for listening.

My code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');



var destino = '/var/www/upload/';
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return  filename + Date.now();
    },
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 200,
        files: 5,
        fields: 5
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());




app.post('/image', upload.single('message'), function (req, res) {


    var file = req.file;
    fs = require('fs')
    fs.readFile(file.path, 'base64', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

/* do something if data*/
        fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
    });

    });

http.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("Conectado e escutando na porta: 8080");


});
```

The error show to me it's it:   Error: request entity too large

```
        at readStream (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:196:17) 
        at getRawBody (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12) 
        at read (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:76:3) 
        at urlencodedParser (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:109:5) 
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) 
        at trim_prefix (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
        at /var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
        at Function.process_params (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
        at next (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
        at expressInit (/var/www/likeyounode/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:33:5)
```

I reviewed all my code and it is only necessary that amount of evidence to show what I want more than that will reveal much of my project.

There are some configurations in the body I did and if you notice they are illustrated in the content, being a doubt will not have all the functions you away running its own application.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are setting any multer configuration and your code seems incomplete.

Comment: Did you ever try my solution? :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In my case, after setting the limit @ **node.js** (webapp)

```js
var express = require('express'); var app = express(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');            
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'})); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit:'50mb'}));
```

I also **(most important)** had to set up the limit @ **nginx**  (webapp reverse proxy)

```
 # Max upload size.
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Comment: thanks, EMX just to make sure a little bit more details about client_max_body_size 50M;  One has to add this line in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.

Comment: for me, just adding the one line to nginx fixed the issue. Here is the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell by all of your code but just by looking at the error, you should be able to set the body post size with the following:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#limits

```
 multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: maxSize }
 })
```

If that doesn't solve your issue, bodyParser also has a limit.
It's options can be found:

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit

```
bodyParser({limit: '4MB'});
```